# How to compute Quadratic Assignment Procedure using R?

Tags: r, sna

I have 3 Networks and i want to measure Structural equivalence with Quadratic Assignment Procedure. I have executed this code but Got this error . can any one help and suggest that i am on right way ?

```
 rm(list=ls())
    getwd()
    library(sna)
    dat=read.csv(file.choose(),header=TRUE)
    dat1=read.csv(file.choose(),header=TRUE) 
    dat2=read.csv(file.choose(),header=TRUE) 

    el=as.matrix(dat)
    g=graph.edgelist(el,directed=FALSE)

    el=as.matrix(dat1)
    g1=graph.edgelist(el,directed=FALSE)

    el=as.matrix(dat2)
    g2=graph.edgelist(el,directed=FALSE)
    #Perform qap tests of graph correlation
     q.12<-qaptest(g,gcor,g1=1,g2=2)
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  as.sociomatrix.sna input must be an adjacency matrix/array, network, or list.
> q.13<-qaptest(g,gcor,g1=1,g2=3)
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  as.sociomatrix.sna input must be an adjacency matrix/array, network, or list.
> 
> #Examine the results
> summary(q.12)
Error in summary(q.12) : object 'q.12' not found
> plot(q.12)
Error in plot(q.12) : object 'q.12' not found
> summary(q.13)
Error in summary(q.13) : object 'q.13' not found
> plot(q.13)
Error in plot(q.13) : object 'q.13' not found
```

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Without knowing your input file, it is difficult to help you.

Comment: Well, there are at least two issues here. First, `graph.edgelist` is a function from the `igraph` package; `sna` won't recognize it. Either send it adjacency matrices or use the `network` function `as.network` to create networks `sna` recognizes. Second, you need to send `qaptest` a list--qaptest(list(g, g1, g2), gcor, g1 = 1, g2 = 2). Right now you are sending it a single network (g).

Comment: q.12<-qaptest(list(g, g1, g2), gcor, g1 = 1, g2 = 2)
Error in fun(dat, ...) : Identical graph orders required in gcor.
now got this error

Comment: means that your networks are not the same size. For qap test, networks need the same number of nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nodes size of two network should be same.. means if one network has 50 nodes the other network should have same set of nodes.. However, no of edges may differ